# CSS Grid with Empty Div

Tags: html, css

I'm a complete noob and learning CSS GRID. I'm trying to create a 2 column card. The first column has an empty DIV with a background image and the second column has some text. The issue comes to play when I am trying assigning column tracks to reverse the two columns using only CSS. I would like the text column first, and the image column second. For some reason, its creating and extra row. Its leaving me with a space above column 1, and a space below the image on column 2. Can anybody be kind enough to explain what's going on? Below is my code pen. Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="cover-image">
        <div class="color-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Get <span class="highlight">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
        <p class="description">Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer 
          experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
        <ul class="benefit-container">
          <li>
            <p class="number">10k+</p>
            <p>COMPANIES</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="number">314</p>
            <p>TEMPLATES</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="number">12M+</p>
            <p>QUERIES</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
/* GLOBAL STYLES */
* {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}

/* COLOR SWATCHES */
:root {
    --dark-blue: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
    --desaturated-blue: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
    --soft-violet: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
    --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --paragraph-white: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    --headings-white:hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
}

/* GENERAL */
body {
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.container {
    max-width: 1110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* CONTENT */
.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 400px;
}

.cover-image {
    background-image: url(https://64.media.tumblr.com/b9a4ac06954b37ce1154a64744b408b2/tumblr_nl3x1k11kS1up9ojio1_1280.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
}

.cover-image {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    position: relative;
}

.color-overlay {
    background-color: var(--soft-violet);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
    opacity: .7;
}

.content {
    grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/webmonkey714/pen/xxdRbVj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) css property. It sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or grid container.

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES */
* {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}

/* COLOR SWATCHES */
:root {
    --dark-blue: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
    --desaturated-blue: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
    --soft-violet: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
    --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --paragraph-white: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    --headings-white:hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
}

/* GENERAL */
body {
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
}

.container {
    max-width: 1110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* CONTENT */
.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 400px;
}

.cover-image {
    background-image: url(https://64.media.tumblr.com/b9a4ac06954b37ce1154a64744b408b2/tumblr_nl3x1k11kS1up9ojio1_1280.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
    order: 1;
}

.color-overlay {
    background-color: var(--soft-violet);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="cover-image">
        <div class="color-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Get <span class="highlight">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
        <p class="description">Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer 
          experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
        <ul class="benefit-container">
          <li>
            <p class="number">10k+</p>
            <p>COMPANIES</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="number">314</p>
            <p>TEMPLATES</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="number">12M+</p>
            <p>QUERIES</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @user3733831 . That works perfectly. As a student learning CSS Grid, I'm still curious as to why my approach isn't working. Assigning column tracks is a valid form of laying out content, and I think knowing why it isn't working can make me a better developer.

Comment: If it works for you, don't forget to accept my answer..